# Horde_Text_Diff_Renderer Colors, etc

Tags: php, horde

Does `Horde_Text_Differ_Renderer` have built-in methods to format the text it outputs?

ie. colors, apply css classes? etc?

Comment: What is your question? So far you've only been describing what you can't (e.g. find something). It's not that you delegate jobs here on SO ;) (I can see your bounty, not that you waste it, I just want to suggest to you to improve you question a little and tell what exactly you're looking for)

Comment: And one example I know of is with Wordpress. They use that class IIRC and it is used with colors (the typical red and green).

Comment: @hakre - is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As you can in the source](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Vendor/Horde/Text/Diff/Renderer.php#L222), Horde *just* add prefix to lines it sees differences in.

For example, for added line, it will use :

```
protected function _added($lines) {        
    return $this->_lines($lines, '> '); // prefix with > 
}
```

So you can modify this class to add whatever you need here, or better, you can override it with your own class modifying only the methods you need to change, leaving the rest untouched.

Comment: I've actually done this already, however, I'm looking for a built-in method to do this instead of changing the original code. Thank you for your time you spent digging around!

Comment: @JamesHuckabone that's why I advised you to override this class with one of yours…

Comment: I'm looking for an official method as opposed to a hack.  Thank you for your time!!

Comment: I don't consider extending a class a hack… That's pure OOP. Anyway, since you can see the source I linked, you can see that there's no build-in method to change that. IMHO, you got 3 choices : Extend the class with your own (thing I'll do, so that even if you update Horde, you'll still have what you want), tell the author via a Github Issue that it should be more modular or even better, do the modification yourself in a fork of that class and ask for a merge.

Comment: You're right, I was just being moody.  Thanks for the great advice!